# How to insert my 1:100 draw from Autocad into a Word document

Tags: image, autocad

I must to insert an 1:100 image I did in Autocad inside a Word document. I just printed in PDF format and it fits a A4. I could do a print screen, paste it on the Word page and crop the boundaries, but it need some very sketchy adjusts to put it back into the correct scale. Also the lines does not render very well. I believe there is a better and correct way to do.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my first question would be, "Why do you need to insert the file into a word document?"

If you must insert it into a word document, you should use the Insert Object process described here -->[PDF into Word Doc](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/insert-pdf-into-word-document/).

This would never be my preferred method though. I would rather convert the word document to PDF and then insert my scaled PDF drawing into the exported word doc PDF. This would keep the integrity of your drawing scale intact.

Just my two cents, which won't get you much.